# TypeScript type for React FunctionComponent that returns exactly one IntrinsicElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a TypeScript type that guarantees that a React `FunctionComponent` eventually renders exactly one HTML element.  That is, it can't be a `string`, a `number`, a `ReactFragment`, a `ReactPortal` (unless, I suppose, that portal returns exactly one HTML element), `null`, or a `boolean`.

My understanding is that a type for all HTML elements is

```ts
type IntrinsicElement = JSX.IntrinsicElements<keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>;

const anIntrinisicElement: IntrinsicElement = <div />;

// @ts-expect-error
const notAnIntrinsicElement: IntrinsicElement = 'foo';
```

and indeed this compiles.

So, I would expect the following to work for a `FunctionComponent` that returns exactly one `IntrinsicElement`:

```ts
type IntrinsicFC<P = unknown> = FC<P> & ((props: P) => IntrinsicElement);

const SuccessFC: IntrinsicFC = () => <div>Goodbye</div>;
const FCWithProps: IntrinsicFC<{ a: number }> = (props: { a: number }) => 
  <div>{props.a}</div>;

// @ts-expect-error
const FragmentFC: IntrinsicFC = () =>
  <>
    <div>Hello</div>
    foo
  </>;

// @ts-expect-error
const NullFC = () => null;

// @ts-expect-error
const TextFC = () => 'foo';
```

Oddly, this does *not* compile.  None of the `// @ts-expect-error` components are actually faulty.

If this *did* work, then I suspect my final type would be:

```ts
type IntrinsicFC<P = unknown> = FC<P> & {
  (props: P): IntrinsicElement | IntrinsicFC;
};

const NestedSuccessFC: IntrinsicFC = () => <SuccessFC />;

// @ts-expect-error
const NestedFragmentFC: IntrinsicFC = () => <FragmentFC />; // erroneously valid
```

So, my question is, why does `IntrinsicElement` reject `string`, `number`, and `null`, but `IntrinsicFC` not, and how can I fix it?

**Update**: I've discovered that `ReactFragment`s, for some reason, successfully compile as `IntrinsicElement`s.  This is probably because `ReactFragment` is defined as `{} | ReactNodeList`, and `{}` is just "anything that isn't nullish".  On the other hand, `ReactFragment` does *not* extend `IntrinsicElement`, so I am not sure why it can be assigned.  That may or may not be the root of the issue.

```ts
type IsIntrinsicElementAReactFragment =
  IntrinsicElement extends ReactFragment ? true : false; // true

type IsReactFragmentAnIntrinsicElement = 
  ReactFragment extends IntrinsicElement ? true : false; // false

// erroneously valid
// @ts-expect-error
const fragmentIsNotAnIntrinsicElement: IntrinsicElement = <>foo</>;

// correctly invalid
// @ts-expect-error
const notAnIntrinsicElement3: IntrinsicElement = <TextFC />;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtsujPlCgOYhIB28AvnAGZQQhwDkUqGXAbgBQQmAE8wSOAEkGUYHQDOwNAFEANkloM4AXjgApAMoANAHSyY8pSo1b6MRQG0A1kjEQWh0xbkLlaprajgC6wkJoEErwKHSW1sABdsEAXDJ+NoH2OvoAPAAmwABucAD0AHzhpaVwAAKOALRIAB6SGE1Q7FARUYrwfdZU0ooAchAwAIJxGUlBDmnx-rZzOdwsEBCCItV1jS1tMB1dPdFwdACu6urDY5PTVktZqekPmckOemeX6uHikjKKRZvFaTUgYCjUYKfIGzbLwFowej5RSIPjkSg0D4AfjgVnOUjSLBQ6kUSAEZRqeKQogkUmGYPRkIcUxhyzhnwZEMxOgRSJRrKe2NxUHxcEJxNJ5J2RJJ1KEO3qiiarSQ7SQnWgJz6rAxwRu4xZMzZzwF71WuXK6wguQqVUptJe1gCRFyAAVPuc6C46BAAO50cqfF2uwMAMjgAAoI2B2GBFGlXQBKPSB00gxO-B0C4Mer0+-2B-TBsO4IRwSMxiBxhOJhZGwU6AA+jseRGEjHCkVORnOaDQSEUiiIddezsInwjyd0gYKxXKAHENvkAEZiJA2wpFSpa+BEADqwBgAAtXbH4y3Mi68Cg0hcQMv1XBGIWK2e0tfb+d74-GFOZ5vyhwSs4zMFBGA3Oc7V2JV9lVQ51WOLttS5YJhwvMcJz-Ms4AtbDy1nLcAAkkCua1SgAvDWA2bCbW3eUakVZUDiOTUkPgEZviITCUy+K4oMY2C1Q1bo2LgAAVBEuP0SceK4K0th3OARgHRF8h7PsByHQgRydFQpMjP8cPU-tBy421tgYvYVSExDenYlSkHyFCHDQ7Nx2kwzcmchgzLo0SFFHY0HAAJh0x4zXgPJjM03z+Ks5iENYuyzgNe5dIbGBQvQoLzW88hx3M+joKYuCWJE5KfTuNM4QAZjC4F2TyCTmnyspKiAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very interesting question.SOme time ago, I spent a lot of time digging into react built in types. This is what I have found/understood:

If you use `jsx` syntax, no way that you will infer some specific types.

Take a look at the type definitions of `FC`

```js
    interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }

    type VFC<P = {}> = VoidFunctionComponent<P>;

    interface VoidFunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }
```

As you might have noticed, every FUnctionCOmponent returns `ReactElement<any,any>`.

This is how `Reactlement` looks like:

```js
    interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
        type: T;
        props: P;
        key: Key | null;
    }
```

We are interested in `T` - type generic argument. It extends `JSXElementConstructor`

```js
    type JSXElementConstructor<P> =
        | ((props: P) => ReactElement | null)
        | (new (props: P) => Component<P, any>);
```

`JSXElementConstructor` is just a recursion. Nothing helpful here.

React native syntax is a way more interesting.

Consider next example:

```js
const foo = React.createElement("a"); // ok
```

This is where magic happens. Take a look at `createElement` typings:

```js
    // DOM Elements
    // TODO: generalize this to everything in `keyof ReactHTML`, not just "input"
    function createElement(
        type: "input",
        props?: InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement> | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): DetailedReactHTMLElement<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>;
    function createElement<P extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T extends HTMLElement>(
        type: keyof ReactHTML,
        props?: ClassAttributes<T> & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): DetailedReactHTMLElement<P, T>;
    function createElement<P extends SVGAttributes<T>, T extends SVGElement>(
        type: keyof ReactSVG,
        props?: ClassAttributes<T> & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): ReactSVGElement;
    function createElement<P extends DOMAttributes<T>, T extends Element>(
        type: string,
        props?: ClassAttributes<T> & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): DOMElement<P, T>;

    // Custom components

    function createElement<P extends {}>(
        type: FunctionComponent<P>,
        props?: Attributes & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): FunctionComponentElement<P>;
    function createElement<P extends {}>(
        type: ClassType<P, ClassicComponent<P, ComponentState>, ClassicComponentClass<P>>,
        props?: ClassAttributes<ClassicComponent<P, ComponentState>> & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): CElement<P, ClassicComponent<P, ComponentState>>;
    function createElement<P extends {}, T extends Component<P, ComponentState>, C extends ComponentClass<P>>(
        type: ClassType<P, T, C>,
        props?: ClassAttributes<T> & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): CElement<P, T>;
    function createElement<P extends {}>(
        type: FunctionComponent<P> | ComponentClass<P> | string,
        props?: Attributes & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): ReactElement<P>;
```

This function knows everything. Do you want `IntrinsicElements`? No problem!

```js
const createElement = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(elem: T) =>
  React.createElement(elem);

const test = createElement("a"); // ok
const test_ = createElement(null); // error
```

Type, you are interested int is : `DetailedReactHTMLElement<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>`

You can find it inside `createElement` overloads.

Feel free to experiment.

Some time ago I wrote two articles about this topic. You can find them in my blog:

[Typing react children](https://catchts.com/typed-react-children)

[Typing react return type](https://catchts.com/react-return-type)

Not strictly related but still might be interesting for you: [Typing react props](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/how-to-type-react-props-as-a-pro-2df2)

I'm not sure I have answered your question but I hope you will find my answer helpful

**UPDATE**

You can also override `FUnctionComponent` interface, it partially helps but still allows React.Fragment:

```js
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>

}

// ok
const Foo: FunctionComponent<{ label: string }> = (props) => {
  return <div></div>
}

// error
const Bar: FunctionComponent<{ label: string }> = (props) => {
  return 42
}

// error
const Baz: FunctionComponent<{ label: string }> = (props) => {
  return null
}

// error
const Bat: FunctionComponent<{ label: string }> = (props) => {
  return 'str'
}

const x = React.Fragment
// no error
const Fragment: FunctionComponent<{ label: string }> = (props) => {
  return <></>
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really help me.  `createElement()` infers its `T` based on `elem`.  Also, I tried declaring a constant of type `DetailedReactHTMLElement<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>` and setting it to `<div>hello</div>` and it failed.  It even failed when I changed `HTMLElement` to `HTMLDivElement`, which confuses me.

Comment: It will work only with `React.createElement`. It does not work with `jsx` syntax

Comment: I don't care if I use the JSX namespace or not, and using one of the definitions of `React.createElement()`, there *should* be a way to create a type, though it may require manually entering a generic type parameter, which would be obnoxious.

Comment: The goal isn't to *create* an element.  It's to restrict a property to *only* functions that return a single element.

Comment: because the crux of the issue *is* fragments.  Everything else works with my JSX approach.

Comment: Links to blog are dead.

Comment: They appear to link to a blog, but not specific articles.  I was also unable to figure out which articles they were intending to link to.  They both redirect to the blog homepage, not a specific article.