# TypeScript type that excludes types with a generic parameter of `any`

Tags: typescript

This is an offshoot of [TypeScript type for React FunctionComponent that returns exactly one IntrinsicElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398560/typescript-type-for-react-functioncomponent-that-returns-exactly-one-intrinsicel).

React defines

```ts
declare namespace JSX {
  type Element = React.ReactElement<any, any>;
}
```

And while I can't find it in `@types/react/index.d.ts`, rendering a `<Fragment>` returns a `JSX.Element`.  So, if I want to define a type for a function that returns exactly one HTML element (i.e. not a `Fragment` unless it has exactly one child, which would defeat its purpose), I somehow need to limit my return type to something like

```ts
type IntrinsicFC = 
  () => Exclude<JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements], ReactElement<any, any>>;
```

(Note: `Exclude<..., ReactElement<any, any>>` does *not* mean what I expected it to; it seems to be identical to `JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]` though I don't understand why.  But, for the sake of this question, assume I *did* know the right type for what I tried to express.)

However, `any` is the death of strong typing, and since every HTML Element extends `ReactElement<any, any>`, this would make my type `() => never`.

Is there a way to exclude a type which is a type alias for `SomeGenericType<any>`?

My latest failed attempt at making an `IntrinsicFC` is:

```ts
type IntrinsicElement = JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements];

type IntrinsicFC<P = void> =
  ((props: P) => IntrinsicElement) extends ((props: P) => JSX.IntrinsicElements[infer U & keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements])
    ? U extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
      ? ((props: P) => JSX.IntrinsicElements[U])
      : never
    : never;
```

This, however, results in `type IntrinsicFC<P = {}> = never;`, because `IntrinsicElement` *always* extends `JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]` as it is the very same definition.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgEkA7GKYJgZ2DQFEAbJCCQs4AXjgApAMoANAHTNW7LrwFCWHANoBrJNQiZJshSzadu-QcJgcAuhSq16isyoBiAYQA8ABTFwANwhgABMAPjFyODgAChiwHDAOAC44HwBKMQiXZQs1a0ykAA8YYRCOWPjElLTM0QjpeRzzVSsNTXZMJCg4AFU4ADI4XX1DRpMlFst1G1t0qOi4AH4+uGLSpnLhvQMjJtNc1pmOBcXlyoSIJNSMrL2J1zy2m01eudPF1KYkAO6Pr5+3QcaAgnHgABFgAFPKlmu4PP4YnUIl4QlCwgALJB8PgQLwAejRATCDnx+LgAAEbABaYp0DC0qA4KDkEFguBuKAoADmMMYBxankRyLgXkx2NxBJJQA)

---

I suspected that when the React team wrote the declaration file, they meant `JSX.Element` to be defined as

```ts
type Element = React.ReactElement<unknown>;
```

but that the type predates TypeScript v3.0.0, which [introduced the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type), and changing it now would be a breaking change.  However, I just tried manually changing the type declaration, and it still doesn't work, so... ‍♀️

Comment: Uh, blagh, this feels like a job for a linter or a library change.  Otherwise you might end up going down the route of [detecting and disallowing `any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927523/disallow-call-with-any/49928360#49928360) which is yucky.

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand what type you want `IntrinsicFC` to be.  If this question is really about react, you might want to tag it as such.  If not, then maybe could you provide a [mcve] that doesn't depend on it?  `JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]` has over 120 members and I can't tell which, if any of them, you want to exclude.  Or if you want to just *transform* each of them to something else, that makes sense, but maybe reduce the problem to just a few input-output relationships.

Comment: Okay, I'll come up with a more minimal example.

Comment: Hmm, the more I've looked at this, the more I'm thinking it's impossible.  `const x = <div />;` *also* makes `x` a `JSX.Element` unless you specifically tell it to be something else.  And even if I do something like `const x: JSX.IntrinsicElements['a'] = <a>foo</a>`, it complains that `Element` is missing properties of `JSX.IntrinsicElements['a']`.