# Why are TSX elements not strongly typed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Consider this:

```
const selectLiteral /*: JSX.Element */ = <select></select>;
const selectCode /*: React.ReactDetailedReactHTMLElement<{}, HTMLElement> */ = React.createElement('select', {});
```

The typing of `createElement` is a bit incomplete due to non-specific `HTMLElement` but that's on react's type definition file.

What I don't get is why do all XML literals get `JSX.Element` instead of specific type? This seems like a deliberate choice? Also applies to custom components.

Comment: This questions are relative to your: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398560/typescript-type-for-react-functioncomponent-that-returns-exactly-one-intrinsicel#answer-68399995 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68502411/typescript-type-that-excludes-types-with-a-generic-parameter-of-any

Comment: Why is there a need to? Usually `JSX.Element` is the "final rendered product" you either return or embed in another component. You shouldn't have to interact with its fields or props.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `React.createElement` has 8 overload signatures. And `ReactDetailedReactHTMLElement` is not a type that is publicly exported by react. That's a lot of complexity for something you, arguably, shouldn't need.