# How to specify specific jsx Element return type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

If I want to define a function that returns a Button element, what is the correct return type of the function?

Is this something that is possible?

Ex:

```
  const clickMeButton = (): Button => {
    return (
      <Button>
        Click Me
      </Button>
    )
  }
```

Comment: RElated questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398560/typescript-type-for-react-functioncomponent-that-returns-exactly-one-intrinsicel , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68502411/typescript-type-that-excludes-types-with-a-generic-parameter-of-any

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
const clickMeButton = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Button>
      Click Me
    </Button>
  )
}
```

Or you can create your custom type and use them:

```
type ButtonType = React.FC;
type ButtonElementType = ReactElement;

const ClickMeButton:ButtonType = (): ButtonElementType => {
  return (
    <Button>
      Click Me
    </Button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have always been using JSX.Element, but I was wondering if  there was a way to be more specific.

Comment: @Chris I am not sure but you can try the code that i've just edited now.